# AWS Change Credential file Location?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-polly

I have .aws/credentials at a different location than the current folder, how do I specify a different location?

```
# Create a client using the credentials and region defined in the [adminuser]
# section of the AWS credentials file (~/.aws/credentials).
session = Session(profile_name="adminuser")
polly = session.client("polly")
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using python boto library

> The shared credentials file has a default location of
> ~/.aws/credentials. You can change the location of the shared
> credentials file by setting the AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE
> environment variable.

e.g. `export AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE=mycustompath`

Then run your python script

[https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html#:~:text=The%20shared%20credentials%20file%20has,section%20names%20corresponding%20to%20profiles](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html#:%7E:text=The%20shared%20credentials%20file%20has,section%20names%20corresponding%20to%20profiles).